# What does the > (greater than bracket) mean beside file names in Eclipse's Package Explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm setting up a new dev machine with Eclipse 3.7 Indigo.  After pulling a my code down from SVN, the source tree in the Package Explorer is intermittently littered with a > to the left of the file name  The parent package names have them too.  *(Note that this is an AspectJ project, but I don't think that matters.)*

[image: Package Explorer]

**What does the > indicate in the Eclipse Package Manager?**

Answer (score 144, accepted):

It means the file has been modified as compared to the version in your source control repository.

Comment: Bingo.  This is different than how it behaved in earlier versions of Eclipse.  There the icon changed.  Probably because of the different SVN client setup.  Hmmm...I don't like.

Comment: OK, have found that this is all configurable in Preferences: Team >> SVN >> Label Decorations.  Thanks for the pointer.  Will accept your answer once the 10 minute time limit is over.

Comment: Still seems to be how it works with Git in 2016, in Eclipse mars 2.  What an ugly UI choice.

Comment: Same here in Neon -- still would like to know where this is documented!

Comment: This is inaccurate. Almost all my files have the angle brackets, and it's always the same two files that don't have them. All files are up-to-date in git. I use git externally, not via Eclipse. \[edit] I uninstalled the git plugin and the angle brackets are gone.