# Greater than symbol in Eclipse beside class

Tags: eclipse, repository, commit, eclipse-kepler

In the image below, what does the *greater than* symbol beside the `Ladder` class mean? The symbol doesn't appear [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm).

[image: Greater than signs next to classes]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do the > (greater than bracket) mean beside file names in Eclipse's Package Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356923/what-do-the-greater-than-bracket-mean-beside-file-names-in-eclipses-package)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `>` before the file name indicates that changes to that file's contents have not yet been committed to a particular source control repository.

Comment: And this differs from the question mark beside the class in that the latter indicates the class hasn't been added at all?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have made changes to Ladder.java file and not comitted them yet. Once you commit them or revert those changes from workspace  ">" will disapper.