# Search modified files in Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, version-control

Eclipse's search view shows a `>` in front of folders or files that have been [modified in version control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8356923/1553851). Other than manually removing results without that symbol, is there some way to exclude unmodified results from a search?

Comment: Which version control you are using?Using Egit?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround for this, no direct solution.

Open `Git Staging` view in eclipse. In Unstaged changes section, all modified files will be listed automatically(with `>` mark). Select any file in it then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Right click on selection then click `Show In > Project Explorer/Package Explorer/Navigator`. Now all modified files will be selected in corresponding view.

Then open search dialog(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and enter the search string and DON'T forget to select search scope as **Selected Resources**.