# Eclipse IDE - meaning of symbol in hierarchy tree

Tags: eclipse

I have noticed a strange symbol next to one of my classes in Eclipse, the symbol is ">".
It appears in the hierarchy tree, [before the name of the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VMkW.png). And, the class cannot be accesed. I have tried renaming, but not has changed...
What does it means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the > (greater than bracket) mean beside file names in Eclipse's Package Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356923/what-does-the-greater-than-bracket-mean-beside-file-names-in-eclipses-packa)

Answer (score 0):

It's a version control label decoration indicating that your file is dirty.

See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/State#Label_Decorations